# genericity of adversarial attacks

Tags: machine-learning

I am a medical doctor working on methodological aspects of health oriented ML. Reproducibility, replicability, generalisability are critical in this area.
Among many questions, some are raised by adversarial attacks (AA).
My questions are the following : suppose I want to check an algorithms from an AA point of view :

- is there a systematic toolbox to be used, relating format of the data, type of models and AA ?
- are AA classified in some sense ?
- are there gold standards in AA ?

Comment: I don't know this area, but I believe ML is a very small subset of it. Relevant general keywords might be "Information security", "Cryptography" and one random method -  "Homomorphic encryption". Wikipedia pages on these could lead to more useful sources.  [Six degrees of Wikipedia](https://www.sixdegreesofwikipedia.com/?source=Medical%20privacy&target=Homomorphic%20encryption) gives one more useful link: "Privacy Enhancing Technologies".